# React Native Firebase returns [auth/account-exists-with-different-credential ]

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I currenlty have multiple login methods like facebook,twitter and google. If i login from facebook and then login back from twitter , it will throw me an error **[auth/account-exists-with-different-credential ]**. What i want to do is link all the accounts.

Some answers says, there is error.email and error.credential on **[auth/account-exists-with-different-credential ]** this kind of error. But there is not.

```
if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
// todo 
          
}
```

What should i do in **todo** section to link the providers.

Comment: Did you do anything like what's described in the documentation on linking providers? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause of the error.

The error response might be different per package.
If you are using the mobile based package of firebase([@react-native-firebase/app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app))
or the web based variant of firebase([firebase/app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app)).

The mobile firebase package supports more functionality for the phone, but it might only return the error message and error code. In the web based variant it support more properties as the email & credential object.

I am also working on a linking account for multiple auth service providers, whenever I get the errorCode: 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential'. The drawback of this flow is that you might need to re-login with a different service provider to make the link work. So this can be quite a drag in the login flow.

Here is a discussion link where I received more information about this topic: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2802